# Automating partitions creation in Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, date, plpgsql, partitioning, dynamic-sql

I am trying to automate partitions in Postgres 10 in a huge table by BY RANGE (date_created).

I've noticed that there is no an automatic creation of partitioned tables, therefore I want to write a procedure to automate the creation of those tables.

I was thinking something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cdi.automating_partitions()
RETURNS TABLE(natural_id text, name text, natural_id_numeric text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   formal_table text;
BEGIN
   FOR formal_table IN
       select '2017-01-01'::date + (n || ' months')::interval months,
       '2013-02-01'::date + (n || ' months')::interval monthsplus
       from generate_series(0, 12) n
   LOOP
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
   'CREATE TABLE cdi.' || 'document' || to_char(months, 'YYYY')  || ''  || to_char(months, 'MM') || ' PARTITION OF cdi.document
 FOR VALUES FROM  (''' ||  to_char(months, 'YYYY')  || to_char(months, 'MM')  || ''',
''' to_char(monthsplus, 'YYYY')  || to_char(monthsplus, 'MM')   ''');'
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I get a syntax error near (

Comment: You can't use `execute` outside of a PL/pgSQL block (and never as part of a SQL query)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the function [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#functions-string-format) in conjunction with `execute` to get a clear and readable code, example:

```
do $do$
declare
    d date;
begin
    for d in
        select generate_series(date '2017-01-01', date '2017-12-01', interval '1 month')
    loop
    execute format($f$
        create table cdi.document%s%s partition of cdi.document
        for values from (%L) to (%L)
        $f$, 
        to_char(d, 'YYYY'), to_char(d, 'MM'), d, d+ interval '1 month');
    end loop;
end 
$do$
```

I have used an [anonymous code block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) as `create table ...` does not generate any results. However, if you want to write a function, note that the function should return `void` and not use `RETURN QUERY`.